# ajax in ajax and NEED return value to first ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have looking for the solution with my case. In other question variable from ajax success will execute like this:

```
$.ajax({
...,
success: function(data) {
    myFunction(data);
});

myFunction(data){
    // process the data here ..
}
```

But in my case I call another ajax(2) with ajax(1). And really need that variable from ajax(2) to ajax(1) for process. My code look like this:

```
$("#formVerify").submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(data){
            var result= call_id(data.id);
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});

function call_id(data) {
    var output = null;
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(result){
            output = result;
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

the `result` will always `null` because I set output to, or sometimes it is `undefined` if I don't set the value to `null`. I tried `async: false` but in my machine it wouldn't work. Need help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember Ajax call doesn't **return** result, you can't use *return statement* in ajax call. You can get the result only using callback/promises.

Change you first ajax call to pass the callback instead of trying to get the return value:

```
 $("#formVerify").submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(data){
            call_id(data.id, function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });
            
        }
    });
});
```

and change your second ajax call_id function to take callback as parameter like this:

```
function call_id(data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Comment: I got error `callback is not defined` right in `callback(result)`

Comment: your call_id should have callback as second parameter, you could also use it as updated one.